# Shift Calendar for SWING

Tags: java, swing, calendar

I may need to implemet a work shift calendar for a java/sql application.  Does anyone know of a free API, or do i have to design the thing from scratch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are plenty of `JCalendar`, `JDatePicker` with various Licencing, but really free Calendar as I know is very good  [SwingX Calendar](http://swinglabs.org/) made by [kleopatra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203657/kleopatra)

Comment: too much honor: all SwingX components are the result of collaborative work :-)

Comment: @kleopatra :-) really, how much, much modesty, I can't found some reason for ...,

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this one:

http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/

Comment: that's excelent, simple JCalendar too +1